# Print table's selected checkbox column data through button click

Tags: javascript

I have a table with multiple columns and each column has a checkbox with unique id.

I want to print only selected columns

```
Sr No   Items   Date         Discription    Quantity    No of Pkgs   Pkg Code
1       Mobile  1/12/2018    Mobile         10          20              12345    
2       Laptop  1/12/2018    Mobile         10          20              456789    
3       Tv      1/12/2018    Mobile         10          20              987654    
4       LCD     1/12/2018    Mobile         10          20              321654    
5       PC      1/12/2018    Mobile         10          20              987321
```

On click of this button through jQuery I want to print selected columns

```
<input type="button" id="Print_button" onclick='printChecked()' value="Print Selected Items"/>
```

```js
function printChecked() {
  var items = document.getElementsByName('acs');
  var selectedItems = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type == 'checkbox' && items[i].checked == true)
      selectedItems += items[i].value + "\n";
  }
  alert(selectedItems);
  window.print();
}
```

Plz Give Me Refrence ForThis Or Any Examples

Comment: https://www.dorcode.com/questions/126/print-specific-div-using-jquery

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The code looks good. Is it not working or what ?

Comment: its not working

Comment: I have removed the jQuery, PHP and CodeIgniter tags as none of them are relevant. Please also give more information than 'it's not working'. What does happen? Does anything print at all? What efforts to debug have you made?

Comment: You are collecting some data in `selectedItems`, but you are still printing the whole, unmodified document with `window.print`. There is absolutely no connection between those two things, so what did you _expect_ to happen?

Comment: it was printing whole page but i want print only selected checkbox data

Comment: In which case I would suggest you create a `@media print` stylesheet which hides all the `tr` elements in the table by default. Then when a checkbox is checked, add a class to the `tr` which allows the elements to be displayed when printed.

Comment: Im confused how do i do that Plz give me refrence

Comment: See in simple way i was try to print selected checkbox data but it was printing whole page im confused how to do that, give me refrence to do that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're doing it a bit wrong.

I will describe, what steps need to be focused.

---

**HTML** - we are using no-print class name to hide elements from print, more details in **CSS** section.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="no-print">
        <th>Sr No</th>   
        <th>Items</th>   
        <th>Date</th>   
        <th>Description</th>   
        <th>Quantity</th>   
        <th>No of Pkgs</th>   
        <th>Pkg Code</th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="no-print">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="1" /></td>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>1/12/2018</td>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>12345</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="no-print">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="2" /></td>
            <td>Laptop</td>
            <td>1/12/2018</td>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>12345</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="no-print">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="3" /></td>
            <td>Netbook</td>
            <td>1/12/2018</td>
            <td>Mobile</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>12345</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" class="no-print" onclick='printChecked()' value="Print Selected Items" />
```

---

**CSS** - all the elements with class no-print will be hidden.

```
@media print {    
  .no-print, .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

---

**JS** - a little bit adjusted, we simply check which row is selected and remove class no-print from that row.

```
function printChecked() {
    const heading = document.querySelector('table > thead > tr');
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       const tr = items[i];
       const input = tr.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
       const isChecked = input.checked

       if (isChecked) {
          heading.classList.remove('no-print');
          tr.classList.remove('no-print');
       }
    }
    window.print();
}
```

---

**DEMO** - https://scrimba.com/c/crgd7Tv

Comment: Ah, nice. - much less processing than mine. However mine does allow for modifications to the print and still allows the original page to be printed without manipulations

Comment: Yep, actually, it depends what we really need. Your solution is more about JS manipulations, mine is more about DOM manipulations :) To be honest, in my opinion, DOM would be easier to understand for guys that are just diving into.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
$("#printBut").on("click",function() {
  var $column = $("#productTable [type=checkbox]:checked");
  if ($column.length) {
    var $newTable = $("<table></table>");
    var $newHead = $("<thead/>").appendTo($newTable);
    var $newBody = $("<tbody/>").appendTo($newTable);
    var ths = $column.map(function() { return '<th>'+$(this).parent().text()+'</th>' }).get();
    $newHead.append('<tr>'+ths+'</tr>');
    var rows = $("#productTable tbody").find("tr").length;
    for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
      var $row = $("<tr/>");
      for (var j=0;j<$column.length;j++) {
        $row.append("<td/>");
      }
      $newBody.append($row);
    }
    $column.each(function(i) {
      var colIdx = $(this).parent().index()+1;
      var $row = $("<tr/>")
      $('table tr td:nth-child('+colIdx+')').each(function(){
        $("tr td:nth-child("+(i+1)+")",$newBody).html($(this).html())
      })
    });
    var $div = $("<div/>").append($newTable);
    console.log($div.html())
    /* uncomment this on your server 
    var w = window.open("","_newwin");
    if (w) {
      w.document.write('<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">'+$div.html()+'</body>');
      w.document.close();
      setTimeout(function(){w.close();},10);
    }
    */
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="productTable">
  <thead>    
    <tr><th>Sr No<input type="checkbox" /></th><th>Items<input type="checkbox" /></th><th>Date<input type="checkbox" /></th><th><input type="checkbox" /></th><th>Description<input type="checkbox" /></th><th>Quantity<input type="checkbox" /></th><th>No of Pkgs<input type="checkbox" /></th><th> Pkg Code<input type="checkbox" /></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Mobile</td><td>1/12/2018</td><td>Mobile</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>12345</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Laptop</td><td>1/12/2018</td><td>Mobile</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>456789</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Tv</td><td>1/12/2018</td><td>Mobile</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>987654</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>4</td><td>LCD</td><td>1/12/2018</td><td>Mobile</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>321654</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>5</td><td>PC</td><td>1/12/2018</td><td>Mobile</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>987321</td></tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="printBut">Print selected</button>
```